# « Équipe d'ingénieurs logiciel » ou « équipe de génie logiciel » ?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot, informatique

Je trouve tous les deux sur Google, mais je suppose que seulement l'un ou l'autre est vraiment correct?

Je traduis « *the software engineering team behind ...* » par

1. *l'équipe d’ingénieurs logiciel derrière ...*
2. *l'équipe de génie logiciel derrière ...*

Je trouve le premier plus naturel, mais je suis pas un locuteur natif. C'est possible que les 2 options sont possibles, auquel cas il ne s'agirait que d'une question d'accentuation entre le travail et les gens…

Answer (score 6):

(étant informaticien de métier et de plus dans le domaine du génie logiciel, je peux m'exprimer sur ce point)

Bien que les deux expressions puissent être utilisées suivant le contexte, la seconde expression "l'équipe de génie logiciel" est moins générique et fait référence à une activité spécifique en informatique : le génie logiciel. 
Cette activité vise à mettre au point des méthodes et outils qui pourront être utilisés par d'autres ingénieurs, par exemple ceux de l'équipe d'ingénieurs logiciel. (par exemple concevoir un outil qui une fois donné à un autre informaticien lui sera utile pour à son tour de concevoir un système/application)

En résumé : l'équipe de génie logiciel fournit des méthodes et outils pour l'équipe d'ingénieurs logiciel.

Il ne faut donc utiliser cette seconde expression que si on a besoin de mettre en avant cette activité spécifique.

Answer (score 3):

Il faut distinguer :

- l'**analyse**, c'est-à-dire le dessin de l'architecture de l'application (*software-analysis*),
- l'écriture du logiciel, ou **programmation** (*software-coding*),
- les **méthodes**, ou **génie logiciel**, pour écrire de façon relativement sûre et efficace, voire gérer les équipes d'analystes et programmeurs (*software-engineering*).

Pour prendre une image dans le bâtiment, la première tâche est celle de l'architecte, la deuxième celle du maçon (et autres corps de métier, agissant selon des plans), la troisième celle du coordinateur des livraisons (pour ne pas commander trop tôt ni trop tard).

Seulement, en informatique, il faut d'abord choisir la méthode selon laquelle on va ensuite analyser et enfin programmer ; ce choix ne vient pas après, mais conditionne toute la réalisation d'un projet, et donc est imposé aux analystes et programmeurs par leur responsables hiérarchiques.

Et pour ne pas prendre de risque, si le contexte ne lève pas toute ambiguïté, je dirais "l'équipe d'informaticiens derrière ...".

Answer (score 3):

En avertissement, s'il s'agit bien de mon domaine professionnel, j'ai fait toute ma carrière dans des multinationales où l'usage de l'anglais et d'un jargon fortement anglicisant dominent, je ne suis pas familier avec les usages du jargon plus fortement francisé (et j'ai déjà entendu bien des choses qui m'ont étonné).

- Je n'ai jamais entendu parler *d’ingénieurs logiciel*, et l'image que le terme évoque n'est pas une traduction de *software engineer* mais de spécialistes d'un logiciel donné.
- *l'équipe de génie logiciel* est pour moi l'équipe servant à mettre au point et supervisant le déploiement des méthodes de génie logiciel sanctifiées par l'entreprise (que ce soit MERISE, TDP ou SCRUM) plus que les équipes les mettant en œuvre, ce que *software engineer* évoque pour moi en premier lieu même si l'anglais peut convenir aux deux.

Je suggère donc plutôt quelque chose comme *l'équipe de programmeurs*, *l'équipe de développeurs*, *l'équipe de développement* ou *l'équipe d'informaticiens*, de n'utiliser *l'équipe de génie logiciel* que s'il s'agit bien du sens évoqué dans mon deuxième point et *équipe d'ingénieurs logiciel* que si d'autres confirment qu'il s'agit bien d'une locution établie avec le sens désiré.

Comment: Tant à l'université que dans les écoles d'ingénieur, le terme "ingénieur logiciel" est très utilisé ; je ne pense pas que ce soit du franglais, mais tout aussi admis que "ingénieur travaux publics", ingénieur matériaux, etc. (apocope).

Comment: @MarkThorin, ce qui est franglisant, c'est mon environnement professionnel et je suis sorti de formation depuis assez longtemps pour que les usages y aient changé depuis (je suis à peu près certain qu'_ingénieur logiciel_ n'était pas utilisé quand j'étudiais, où j'étudiais, nous avions des _ingénieurs en informatique_ ou des _ingénieurs informaticiens_ — même deux filières différentes, une propre, une comme spécialisation auxiliaire d'_ingénieur électricien_ — mais pas d'_ingénieurs logiciel_), mais si l'usage a changé, il ne s'est pas encore diffusé jusqu'à moi.

Answer (score 2):

Le titre de "***ingénieur***" en France a un sens et un diplôme spécifique, [réglementé](http://www.cti-commission.fr/). (équivalent master 2 université)
A ce titre, il est attendu des "ingénieurs" logiciel qu'ils puissent accomplir toutes les taches mentionnées ci-dessus :

- autonomie dans la maîtrise d'oeuvre du projet
- analyse
- programmation
- intégration / déploiement / support

Answer (score 2):

Généralement, on traduit « the software engineering team » par « l'équipe de développeurs ».

Il n'y a pas forcément que des ingénieurs dans une équipe de « software engineering », il peut il y avoir des développeurs qui ont un niveau de technicien. Donc la traduction « Équipe d'ingénieurs logiciel » me gêne un peu en ce sens, sauf s'il n'y a en effet que des ingénieurs dans l'équipe en question.

Enfin, la seconde traduction « équipe de génie logiciel » ne me paraît pas bonne tout simplement.

Answer (score 0):

> *Génie militaire* : art des fortifications (le petit Robert)

... d'où l'acception du mot comme étant l'art de protéger, de stabiliser les armées, ou alors celui de permettre aux troupes de se déployer.

Un projet informatique d'envergure s'appuie donc sur le génie logiciel qui assure des ressources physiques et logistiques opérationnelles, fiables, pérennes.

Les deux phrases proposées peuvent être équivalente dans ce genre de contexte :

> - Le projet s'appuie sur une équipe de génie logiciel expérimentée ...
> - Les ingénieurs logiciels fournissent tout ce dont les informaticiens ont besoin pour mener à bien le projet.

Comment: Il y a heureusement bien d'autres génies que le militaire : civil, maritime, forestier, chimique, etc., avec à chaque fois l'idée d'organisation, de méthode, de savoir-faire.